# How to create AWS SSM Parameter from Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-ssm

I am trying to copy AWS SSM parameter(for cloudwatch) from one region to another. I have the json which is created as a String in one region.

I am trying to write a terraform script to create this ssm parameter in another region.
According to the terraform documentation, I need to do this

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  name  = "foo"
  type  = "String"
  value = "bar"
}
```

In my case value is a json. Is there a way to store the json in a file and pass this file as value to the above resource? I tried using jsonencode,

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "my-cloudwatch" {
  name  = "my-cloudwatch"
  type  = "String"
  value = jsonencode({my-json})
```

that did not work either. I am getting this error
**Extra characters after interpolation expression** I believe this is because the json has characters like quotes and colon.

Any idea?

Comment: "I tried using jsonencode, that did not work either" - what exactly did you try? What errors did you get? What does it mean "did not work either."? What exactly is happening that it does not work?

Comment: edited my question

Answer (score 3):

I tested the following & this worked for me:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "my-cloudwatch" {
  name  = "my-cloudwatch"
  type  = "String"
  #value = file("${path.module}/ssm-param.json")
  value = jsonencode(file("${path.module}/files/ssm-param.json"))
}
```

./files/ssm-param.json content:

```
{
    "Value": "Something"
}
```

and the parameter store value looks like this:

```
"{\n    \"Value\": \"Something\"\n}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this issue the $ in the CW config is causing the problem. Use $$

"Note: If you specify the template as a literal string instead of loading a file, the inline template must use double dollar signs (like $${hello}) to prevent Terraform from interpolating values from the configuration into the string. "

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html

```
    "metrics": {
    "append_dimensions": {
        "AutoScalingGroupName": "$${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
        "ImageId": "$${aws:ImageId}",
        "InstanceId": "$${aws:InstanceId}",
        "InstanceType": "$${aws:InstanceType}"
    },
```

I prefer Pauls aproach though.

Answer (score -1):

You need to insert your json with *escaped quotas*, is a little trick in AWS, and you need to parse this when retrieve:

```
const value = JSON.parse(Value)
```

Example of insert:

```
 "Value": "\"{\"flag\":\"market_store\",\"app\":\"ios\",\"enabled\":\"false\"}\"",
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` is not TF code.

Comment: JSON.parse is to be used in your application, you will insert the value in TF using escaped quotas, and when retrieve the value, you need to parse this in json.

Comment: My point is, why would you use JavaScript if TF has build in function for the same thing?

Comment: Because only value that ssm parameter accept is string, then you need to insert value as string and parse them into your application to read the json.